# in html templates for email can I use mso | IE

Tags: html, email, templates, outlook, html-email

I have a code with if condition:

```
<!--[if mso | IE]> ... <![endif]-->
```

I don't know the answer if I can use | as the divider for mso and internet explorer or if I should do two "if's"

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `|` in the conditional statements.

Outlook Version MSO Comment Code

Codes to target specific email clients:

| Outlook Version | MSO Comment Code |
| --- | --- |
| All versions of Outlook | <!–[if mso]> code <![endif]–> |
| Outlook 2000 | <!–[if mso 9]> code <![endif]–> |
| Outlook 2002 | <!–[if mso 10]> code <![endif]–> |
| Outlook 2003 | <!–[if mso 11]> code <![endif]–> |
| Outlook 2007 | <!–[if mso 12]> code <![endif]–> |
| Outlook 2010 | <!–[if mso 14]> code <![endif]–> |
| Outlook 2013 | <!–[if mso 15]> code <![endif]–> |
| Outlook 2016 and 2019 | <!–[if mso 16]> code <![endif]–> |

| Code Definition | MSO Comment Code |
| --- | --- |
| gt Greater than | <!–[if gt mso 14]> Greater than MSO 2010 <![endif]–> |
| lt Less than | <!–[if lt mso 12]> Less than MSO 2007 <![endif]–> |
| gte Greater than or equal to | <!–[if gte mso 15]> Greater than or equal to MSO 2013 <![endif]–> |
| lte Less than or equal to | <!–[if lte mso 11]> Less than or equal to MSO 2003 <![endif]–> |
| `|` or | <!–[if mso 9 `|` mso 10]> If MSO 2000 or 2002 <![endif]–> |
| ! not | <!–[if !mso 9]><!–> If not MSO <!–<![endif]–> |